# Python3 to build a simple fitness tool

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is just a fun project I thought would be cool to do, but I'm struggling to figure it out.

```
plates = [100, 45, 35, 25, 10, 5, 2.5]
goal_weight = 425
starting_weight = 45
while goal_weight > starting_weight:
```

My idea was to iterate through plates with a while loop. I need each number to max out into the goal weight (100 goes into 450 4 times) then moves onto the next number and attempts there, to show the ideal way to load the bar. But I may be on the wrong track here.

Example: 250 = 45lb bar(starting_weight), two 100lb plate, two 2.5lb plate
         425 = 45lb bar, two 100lb, four 45lb

Wanting it to print something like: Two 100's, two 45's, two 10's

Comment: Look up the [change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)

Comment: Whats the desired output?, and BTW i don't fully understand the question here

Comment: The output should be the optimal way to load the bar with weight. Which means to give priority to bigger plates over smaller. for example, if you are trying to load 100lb on one side of the bar, it's better to load one 100lb plate than two 45lb + one 10lb plate, but the problem I'm running into, is that in order for 100lb to be able to be used it has to be able to be used twice, one for each side. So if you use the 100lb plates, that adds 200lb to the total weight

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little program to find the right combinations of weight plates. Note the function zip that combines the list of number of weight plates with the list of weights. `list(zip(nweights, weights))` forming a list of tuples, for example `[(4, 100), (0, 45) ... (0, 2), (0, 2.5)]`

```
weights=[100, 45, 35, 25, 10, 5, 2, 2.5]
targetweight = int(input('What is the target weight: '))

nweights = []
remaining = targetweight
for  i, weight in enumerate(weights):
    nweights.append(int(remaining/ weight))
    remaining = remaining - nweights[i]*weights[i]
    if remaining == 0:
        break

listweights=zip(nweights, weights)
for weight in listweights:
    print(f'you need {weight[0]} of weight {weight[1]} pound')

if remaining !=0:
    print(f'the correct weight combination cannot be found,'
          f'the remaining weight is: {remaining} pound')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I'm going to play around with it to try and understand it better. Still a noob! Lol

Comment: Any idea how I could tweak this to make it to where if it can't fit 2 plates, then it moves to the next weight? Example, for 230lb input I'm gettingWhat is the target weight: 230
you need 1 of weight 100 pound
you need 1 of weight 45 pound
you need 1 of weight 35 pound
you need 0 of weight 25 pound
you need 0 of weight 10 pound
you need 1 of weight 5 pound

Comment: What I'd like the weight output to be for the 230lb example is: four 45's,   two 25's. My instinct is to use modulo % 2 == 0, somewhere in this, just not really sure where.

Comment: So you want the weights in pairs (I suppose to balance bar ... one at each end) I think you just need to double the plates so the list will be 90, 70, 50, 20 and so on ... and then execute the same algorithm.

Comment: Check the answer I posted above, that's what I ended up with after messing around with it for a little while. Works just like I imagined it! Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with. Appreciate the help, guys!

```
weights=[100, 45, 35, 25, 10, 5, 2.5]
target_weight = int(input('How much weight do you need? '))
bar_weight = int(input('Enter bar weight: '))

nweights = []
remaining = target_weight - bar_weight
for  i, weight in enumerate(weights):
    if int(remaining / weight) % 2 == 0:
        nweights.append(int(remaining/ weight))
    else:
        nweights.append(int(remaining/ weight) - 1)
    remaining = remaining - nweights[i]*weights[i]
    if remaining == 0:
        break

listweights=zip(nweights, weights)
print(f'{bar_weight}lb bar')
for weight in listweights:
    if weight[0] >= 2:
        print(f"{weight[0]} | {weight[1]}'s")

if remaining !=0:
    print(f'the correct weight combination cannot be found,'
          f'the remaining weight is: {remaining} pound')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think your solution works, though perhaps the below snippet is more logical... 
(using a bit of numpy array methods)

```
import numpy as np

weights=np.array([100, 45, 35, 25, 10, 5, 2.5])
weights=weights*2
target_weight = int(input('How much weight do you need? '))

nweights=[]
remaining = target_weight
for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
    nweights=np.append(nweights, int(remaining/ weight))
    remaining = remaining - nweights[i]*weights[i]
    if remaining == 0:
        break

nweights = nweights*2
weights=weights*0.5
weightlist=zip(nweights, weights)

barweight=0
for weight in weightlist:
    print(f"{weight[0]} | {weight[1]}'s")
    barweight=barweight+weight[0]*weight[1]

print(f'total weight: {barweight} pound')

if remaining !=0:
    print(f'the correct weight combination cannot be found,'
          f'the remaining weight is: {remaining} pound')
```